# indirect download link using webApi and angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, httpresponsemessage

I use Web Api (C#) to create an indirect download link using below codes:

WebApi Code :

```
var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
  {
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
    Content = new StreamContent(file)
  };
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
           new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
return httpResponseMessage;
```

AngularJs Code :

```
var response = mainService.DownloadFile('api/download/file?id=1'); // $http get
response.then(function (resp) {
                        // Do Nothing                      
}, function (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
});
```

When download manager is installed on the system (similar IDM) Everything is working properly.

but without download manager The browser does not show the download dialog. Neither in Chrome nor in FireFox

I Checked Network Tab in Inspect Element. My Request returned 200 http code and data received but browser not show any dialog for start download.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use use [angular-file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-file-saver).

```
 response.then(function (resp) {
      var data = new Blob([resp], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
      FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'filename');                    
    }, function (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
    })

angular
  .module('fileSaverExample', ['ngFileSaver'])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['FileSaver', 'Blob', ExampleCtrl]);
```